# View pager with custom time interval for each image

Tags: android

I have a view pager in my activity in which I want to show images which is from gallery. Now I want to give time interval for each image to stay in view pager screen. How can I achieve this ?

I tried this code.
I get list in which image and duration are settled.

```
for( int i=0;i<lst.size();i++){
        int period=Integer.parseInt(lst.get(i).getDuration());

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public synchronized void run() {
                LandingActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public synchronized void run() {
                        if(viewPager.getCurrentItem()==lst.size()-1){
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                        }
                        else{
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem()+1);
                        }}
                });

            }
        },100,period);}
```

Comment: https://github.com/Trinea/android-auto-scroll-view-pager, try this linke buddy

Comment: but i don't want auto scrolling..i want different time duration for different image.